SSH connection prompts for a password
Good afternoon
xUbuntu x64 system
( Linux 52410205 5.15.0-75- generic #82~04/20/2011-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 7 19:37:37 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
)
The problem is this: there is a device on the local network that needs to be logged in via SSH without a password (Only the encryption key when first connected, click YES and that's it)
On all devices, it logs in without a password (and there is no password), on this computer it asks for a password.
The user's rights to the folder .ssh tried to install did not help. What to watch?

OS xUbuntu x64 20.04  Here is the OS version. What other data needs to be provided to complete the picture? reinstalling the SSH client did not help

I suggest applying security fixes asap, as you're using a kernel that appears to have not been updated in over a year (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/linux-image-5.15.0-75-generic where current version is 5.15.0.121.131~20.04.1

And will updating the kernel help with this problem?
I have a fleet of 30 machines with the same Kernel version, does not have this problem.

You've provided few specifics as to your install, and those few specifics show you're behind on at least one important security package, so I cannot know what other packages & flaws are left unmaintained/unpatched on your system, nor effects of you leaving your system vulnerable to flaws for over a year.. The lack of security maintenance maybe the significant actual cause to the issue you're aware of & potentially others (ie. your procedures needing attention maybe the largest detail evident in your question!)
